# Using Data Attributes to Target and Update Variables With Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to know how you can target and update variables by using data attributes.

[Link to JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kd2mp90b/5/)

Html

```
<label>Update Foo</label>
<input type="range" class="slider"  min="1" max="100" step="1" value="50" data-var="foo">

<label>Update Bar</label>
<input type="range" class="slider"  min="1" max="100" step="1" value="10" data-var="bar">
```

JavaScript

```
var foo = 50, // when slider is changed these variables are updated
        bar = 10;

// update global variable
function updateVariable(variable, value) {
  variable = value;
  console.log(foo);
  console.log(bar);

  // other function called here that uses foo and bar
}

// input even listener
$('.slider').on("change mousemove", function() {
    updateVariable($(this).data("var"), $(this).val());
});
```

The reason I would like to know how to do this, is because I am trying to figure out a way to have multiple input elements that will be updating variables, while keeping the JS simple.  Which is why the event doesn't just set `foo = $(this).val()`  Before I was making an event listener and function for each input element - so, I'd like to know a more efficient way of handling this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method used won't work properly. It's basically saying `$(this).data("var") = $(this).val()` rather than updating the variable - which is the goal.  To fix this, I made `foo` and `bar` properties as an object.

```
var myObject = {
    foo: 50,
    bar: 10
};

// input even listener
$('.slider').on("input", function() { //remove mouseover event to hide spam
    myObject[$(this).data("var")] = $(this).val();
    console.log("Foo: " + myObject.foo + " Bar: " + myObject.bar);
});

// Alternatively you can access properties objects like this  myObject["foo"] as well.
```

**[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/kd2mp90b/11/)**

This allows for easy access to these properties, and allows them to be updated in a much simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you would need to pass three things to your `updateVariable()` method; the element to be updated, the name of the `data-*` attribute to update and the value to set. Something like this:

```
// update global variable
function updateVariable(el, dataAttr, value) {  
    $(el).data(dataAttr, value);
}

// input even listener
$('.slider').on("change mousemove", function() {
    updateVariable(this, 'var', this.value);
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/kd2mp90b/1/)

That being said, I believe this extraction to be completely redundant. All you're doing is wrapping jQuery's own `data()` method and adding no extra business logic or functionality. You may as well just call `data()` from within each event handler.

Comment: I understand your point on redundancy, but perhaps I'm not following the example.  From what I can tell, the `foo = 50` after the slider is moved.

Comment: That's right. The `foo` variable is pointless if you have multiple input elements. You would need to read the attributes directly from the element  instead.

Comment: I reworked the example slightly.  Of course in this example `foo` and `bar` are pointless, but let's say they're using in other parts of the code where they have purpose. Would a method similar to mine be viable to make updates to these variables and then used elsewhere?  Could this all be done in the in the event handler?